# Python - return the list of lists in lst that contain only integers?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-forms, nested-loops

```
def only_evens(lst):
    """
    Return a list of the lists in lst that contain only even integers. 

    >>> only_evens([[1, 2, 4], [4, 0, 6], [22, 4, 3], [2]])
    [[4, 0, 6], [2]]
    """
    even_lists = []
    condition = True 

    for sublist in lst:
        for num in sublist: 
            if num % 2 != 0: 
                condition = condition and False
        if condition == True: 
            even_lists.append(sublist)

    return even_lists
```

I don't understand why this keeps returning an empty string? Intuitively, this makes sense? Your help is greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for way too long.

**Edit: Thank you all so much! I get it now :).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `condition` outside the loops. That should be reinitialized for each of the sublists and `condition = condition and False` will always evaluate to `False`, that should have been `condition = False`

```
for sublist in lst:
    condition = True
    for num in sublist: 
        if num % 2 != 0: 
            condition = False
            break
```

This can be done with `all` function, like this

```
return [sublist for sublist in lst if all(item % 2 == 0 for item in sublist)]
```

**Sample run**

```
def only_evens(lst):
    return [sublist for sublist in lst if all(item % 2 == 0 for item in sublist)]

print only_evens([[1, 2, 4], [4, 0, 6], [22, 4, 3], [2]])
# [[4, 0, 6], [2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

thefourtheye has answered your question. But use this, it it much 'simpler':

```
[sublst for sublst in lst if all(x%2 == 0 for x in sublst)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `condition and False`

On the python prompt:

```
>>> True and False
False
>>> False and False
False
```

Also I redid the code to use the yield statement, and the [for..else](http://psung.blogspot.com.au/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html) loop control magic, just for fun:

```
def only_evens(lst):
    for sub_lst in lst:
        for num in sub_lst:
            if num % 2 != 0:
                break
        else:
            yield sub_lst

print list(only_evens([[1, 2, 4], [4, 0, 6], [22, 4, 3], [2]]))
```